# Android - Get a pixel from a RAW format Image

Tags: java, android, image, raw

It is possible to convert a pure RAW_SENSOR Image to a bitmap with 16bits of precision and get their pixels out of it?

Comment: if you figured out the solution, post it please.

Answer (score 3):

A RAW "image" is not really an image. It represents the raw (hence the name) sensor data from the camera. To get a bitmap you would need to "develop" the photo.

However a good, general-purpose algorithm for developing a RAW photo is very hard to develop. If I knew a bit more about your situation I could suggest a possible solution but I think your best bet is either using the developed image directly or find some way to convert it using a preexisting algorithm.

I strongly recommend the former because the phone's built-in algorithm will most likely be better than whatever library you might find.

Comment: You are right however the only problem with built-in algorithms is that they convert a 16-bit raw data into a 8-bit "readable" image. So information is lost in the process

Comment: I may have misunderstood but I'm pretty sure that RAW files store more data because they are an inherently different format. Naturally you're losing data by developing the image but the number of bits in the resulting image is not the actual culprit.

Comment: Well I finally managed to do this, thanks for your help anyway I'll post my solution if anyone asks

Comment: Definitely post it!

Comment: @Jotarata Can you post your solution? Thanks.